# SQL How do I generate a row with value 0 of customers in days without order

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I would like to create a query that takes all the dates of the year 2023 (in this case I'm using the order table as an auxiliary table, which is for order registration to get the dates, it always has a date for every day) and then give left join with all client ids how many orders you have each day and if you don't have any orders that day, return 0. I put the client_id 10552 as an example, but there would be several others.

I'm using only one table, the **order**, which has the orders placed, where I'm going to use it to get the dates of the year and also the order quantity by client_id.

Example of some information that comes from the **order** table when I do a **select * from order**:

| created_at | order_status_id | client_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-04-05 22:19:29.000 | 3 | 10,282 |
| 2018-04-22 23:47:36.000 | 3 | 2 |
| 2018-04-25 23:42:22.000 | 3 | 11 |
| 2018-04-06 19:54:33.000 | 4 | 2 |
| 2018-04-09 12:11:06.000 | 3 | 2 |

I'm trying to use the following query to do what I want:

```
with Datas as (
select distinct 
   CAST(o.created_at AS DATE) datas
from platform_bs."order" o
where date_format(o.created_at, '%Y') = '2023'
order by 1
),-- here I put it to list all the dates from 2023 until now
count_orders_client as(
SELECT
   datas,
   od.client_id,
   nullif(count(od.id),0) as count
from Datas as dt
left join platform_bs."order" od ON dt.datas = CAST(od.created_at AS DATE)
group by 1,2
order by 1,2
)-- here I do a left join to get the dates, client id and a count and where should I do it if there were no records on the day, it would return 0
select * from count_orders_client where client_id = 10552
```

I would like it to return this:

| datas | client_id | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 10552 | 1 |
| 2023-01-02 | 10552 | 1 |
| 2023-01-03 | 10552 | 0 |
| 2023-01-04 | 10552 | 0 |
| 2023-01-05 | 10552 | 0 |
| 2023-01-06 | 10552 | 0 |
| 2023-01-07 | 10,552 | 1 |
| 2023-01-08 | 10,552 | 2 |
| 2023-01-09 | 10552 | 0 |
| 2023-01-10 | 10552 | 0 |
| 2023-01-11 | 10552 | 0 |
| 2023-01-12 | 10552 | 0 |

But when run it returns like this:

| datas | client_id | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 10,552 | 1 |
| 2023-01-02 | 10,552 | 1 |
| 2023-01-07 | 10,552 | 1 |
| 2023-01-08 | 10,552 | 2 |
| 2023-01-13 | 10,552 | 1 |
| 2023-01-23 | 10,552 | 1 |
| 2023-02-27 | 10,552 | 1 |

I'm not getting the part of the left join joining the dates of the year 2023 with the order table to return the values ​​0. What should I do?

Edit1: AWS Athena is being used

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text

Comment: sorry, i fixed the text with the informations

Comment: tag your database

Comment: Is this query always going to just take a single Client ID as the parameter?  In the case of your example, those days that have a count of 0 for a particular client, then the Client ID would be Null - so because you're adding "where client_id = 10552", you'll be specifically excluding those "Null" rows

Comment: Please tag the database. Are you certain that client 10552 has 313 orders on 2023-01-01? This is in addition to the comment by @craig (you'll never see 0 count because you're filtering it out)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with this forum. I put all the information that was asked in the comments on the post

Comment: To get the missing dates you should left join it with a date dimension which contains all the dates, or generate one at query time

Comment: If `order` table has all the dates, then you need to flip your join condition. The one with all the dates needs to be on the left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually to generate date ranges (up to 10000 elements) I use [`sequence`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#sequence) (it makes everything a bit clear and manageable), so you can try the following:

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(created_at, order_status_id, client_id) as (
    values (timestamp '2023-04-05 22:19:29.000',    3,  '11'),
        (timestamp '2023-04-06 23:47:36.000',   3,  '2'),
        (timestamp '2023-04-07 23:42:22.000',   3,  '11'),
        (timestamp '2023-04-06 19:54:33.000',   4,  '2'),
        (timestamp '2023-04-08 12:11:06.000',   3,  '2')
),
-- query parts
clients as ( -- find all unique clients
    select distinct client_id
    from dataset
),
client_dates as ( -- create cartesian product of clients and dates
    select *
    from clients,
    -- use here needed start and end for `sequence`:
    unnest(sequence(date '2023-04-04', date '2023-04-09', interval '1' day)) as t(dt) 

)

select cd.client_id, dt, count(order_status_id) count
from client_dates cd
left join dataset d
    on cd.dt = date(created_at) and cd.client_id = d.client_id
group by cd.client_id, cd.dt;
```

Output:

| client_id | dt | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2023-04-04 | 0 |
| 2 | 2023-04-05 | 0 |
| 2 | 2023-04-06 | 2 |
| 2 | 2023-04-07 | 0 |
| 2 | 2023-04-08 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-04-09 | 0 |
| 11 | 2023-04-04 | 0 |
| 11 | 2023-04-05 | 1 |
| 11 | 2023-04-06 | 0 |
| 11 | 2023-04-07 | 1 |
| 11 | 2023-04-08 | 0 |
| 11 | 2023-04-09 | 0 |

Comment: I tested your query by replacing the first cte with my table: **with dataset( select created_at, 
order_status_id, client_id from platform_bs."order")** and even then it was not, it continues to bring the same dates that have value.

Comment: @vichay _" it continues to bring the same dates that have value. "_ - please elaborate.

Comment: @vichay as you can see in the provided query there are only 5 rows of data and far more dates produced in the sample query results (also I fixed small join match bug).

Comment: I meant that it continues to return the same values ​​from the last table that I presented in my question, which is only the days that have orders, it does not bring the days without orders (0)

Comment: Thank you, with this solution adjusted by you, I managed to get the result I wanted!

Comment: @vichay was glad to help! Though the adjustment should not have affected the number of days in the result, only `count`